# Google Spell check URI not working

Tags: javascript, spell-checking, jspell

http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en
can any one help me finding google spell check API Url

Comment: Did you ever found why it was shut down and why it isn't working ? Any alternate urls or change in urls ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link and replace test with your suggested word - www.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=test

Comment: It is not the same, that uri gives you suggestion for searches not spell correction

Comment: I am looking for a Spell checker API will Google provides slimier to this one http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en

Answer (score 9):

From searching around it appears the Google spell service is no longer available. It was never officially supported so I guess it just went away.

I've just replaced my implementation with After the Deadline. This is a pretty impressive project, has a very nice jQuery plugin (much nicer UI for textareas than jquery-spellchecker which is what I had previously) as well as a simple REST service.

http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=jQuery